# substr to char c++ no array

Tags: c++, substring

Like the title says I am trying to convert a substr to a char. Ultimately what I am trying to do is tell with a substr is a upper or lowercase letter, I was given the hint that the best way to do that is using the ascii values. This is what I have

```
for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
  char a = a.substr(i,1);
 if(a>=65&&a<=90){
   uppercase++;
 }
}
```

I get this error here:

```
string_info.cpp:34:16: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a
      structure or union
     char a = a.substr(i,1);
```

I understan that its not working because substr outputs a string and not a char, but what I dont understand is how to get a hold of those ascii values. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `substr` will return a `std::string`, not a char. You could use substr combined with the `[ ]` operator or use it on the source-string directly...

Comment: `if (a>=65&&a<=90)` --> `if( (a>='A') && (a<='Z') )`

Comment: @Blacktempel wont that make it an array? I'm trying to avoid using an array.

Comment: a is a char type and substr is a function invoked using string object.

Comment: @ShankarShastri right, I mentioned that I new thats why it wasnt working. It didnt work either when I put a.substr(i,1) directly into the if statement either

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you even have to use substr? You code is basically just walking the down the string character by character. For that you can use `[]` or `at`

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length();i++) {
    char c = a[i];
    /*
        Can also use
        char c = a.at(i);
     */

    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        uppercase++;
    }
}
```

Also note your code of `char a = a.substr(i, 1);` is wrong because `substr` returns a `string` and you are also redeclaring `a`.

Comment: I tried a.at(i) and I got     string_info.cpp:34:16: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a
      structure or union
     char a = a.at(i);

Comment: You're making the same mistake you made before. Look at the code I wrote. It is `char c = a.at(i);`. You are using `char a = a.at(i);` which is wrong.

Comment: Oh God. Thanks so much, ive been stuck on this for hours. Thanks so much @MobileBen

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using substr, at, or operator[] I would suggest to use a range based for loop:

```
  std::string a = "Test";
  int uppercase = 0;
  for(const auto& c : a)
  {
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      uppercase++;
  }
```

And instead of using the ASCII value it would be better to use the isupper function:

```
  std::string a = "Test";
  int uppercase = 0;
  for (const auto& c : a)
  {
    if(isupper(c))
      uppercase++;
  }
```

Comment: lol, i was gonna suggest it but wasn't sure if he was using C++11

Comment: Hehe, I answered using C++11 because he wasn't specific about what he is using and such an answer wasn't here yet. Anyway in my opionion if he can use C++/C++14 he should to so.